# Selenium Webdriver - findElement atom issue

Tags: selenium

SELENIUM WEBDRIVER - IE

I'm trying to click on a link by using the following command:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Previous orders")).click();
```

and I'm getting this error ... I could make it work some times but most of the time I get this error, it's intermitent, any ideas?

```
> Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.50.0.0
Listening on port 25630
Only local connections are allowed
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: A JavaScript error was encountered executing the findElement atom. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 46 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.50.1', revision: 'd7fc91b', time: '2016-01-29 19:04:49'
System info: host: 'ABC598-L1BCDL9', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:25630/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 9865fcae-fa06-46b5-a621-d8390978c515
*** Element info: {Using=link text, value=Previous orders}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

Main Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.security.UserAndPassword;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        String cartId = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type the Cart ID:");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\USER_ADMIN\\Downloads\\Selenium Webdriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities returnCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        returnCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false);
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(returnCapabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://k06proxy012.sby.com/procurement/buyondemand/common/enUS/index.html");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log in to Buy on demand (Bond)")).click();

        login(driver);

        // START
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Previous orders")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Search previous orders")).click();
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("FIELD1"))).selectByVisibleText("Cart ID");
        driver.findElement(By.id("VALUE1")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("VALUE1")).sendKeys(cartId);
        driver.quit();

    }

    public static void login(WebDriver driver) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("user", "pass"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do any Selenium commands work in your IE11?

Comment: Does clicking on the link cause a browser alert?

Comment: @AlexCharizamhard Yes, all the commands I use on the scripts works on IE 11, I've downloaded the IE 11 webdriver from the Microsoft. The browser does not show any alert or anything, it just stops and when I go back to Eclipse I see this log message, but no warnings or anything is displayed when it happens

Comment: I mean does the link cause a popup when doing manually?

Comment: @AlexCharizamhard nope, it just goes to another page, it's a simple link :) ... now I just tested and everything worked, and I ran a second time and I got this error ... it's totally intermitent

Comment: Does the page previous orders rely a lot on cookies?

Comment: @AlexCharizamhard that's a good question, I don't have the knowledge about behind the scenes, I'm a tester here at work trying to automate some daily tasks, but this error does not only happen on this link ... most of the time it happens on this first link, other times it click on several links and crashes in the last links

Comment: If you change your selector to a different type, ID or Css for example, do you still see the intermittent error?

Comment: @Sanjuro8998, do you have multiple users logging in/out between browser window sessions?

Comment: @MarkRowlands I will try using different selectors and see what happens.

Comment: @AlexCharizamhard nope, just one user logged in, I've updated my question with the main code for analysis

Comment: I am betting it has to do with your Alert handling in the Login method, because I am pretty positive that Selenium uses Javascript to handle this. Try sending enter to bypass the alert and see if this is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn protected mode on IE

1. Click/tap on tools on the menu bar, and Internet Options
2. In the Security tab, select every zone and turn off protected mode

else can you write the main's code

Comment: I've updated my question with the main code, and I turned off protected mode on IE 11 and I will do some run tests to see if this error happens again

Comment: try to edit your code with this:

DesiredCapabilities returnCapabilities= DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
returnCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(returnCapabilities);

Comment: Same thing happening, I edited like this and sometime it works and sometime it does not ... I wish I could not use IE at all but the application I test needs to be validated on IE :-(

Comment: try to delete cookies in your browser and turn off protected mode of all zone

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the error is caused by erroneous code on your part. I tried upgrading to IEDriverServer 2.50 today and started receiving the same error. I returned to using 2.48 as a temporary workaround. Other newer versions may work between the two, this is just what I used previously.

Also see this recent issue on the project's Github page: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1590

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i found the reproducable case.
Check this issue https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2421

The point is in this javascript instruction:

```
var Number="рпоп";
```

Note, that if you write "number" (first small letter) - it will be working.
It seems the problem is in incorrect javascript code parsing.